# Does worklight uses phonegap framework internally?

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I was going through a comparison document between Phonegap and worklight on IBM's site (link below).

http://www.worklight.com/assets/pdf/Worklight%20vs%20PhoneGap%20-%20Comparison.pdf

One line which caught my attention in this document is -

"Worklight utilizes the PhoneGap framework to deliver a uniform bridge between standard web technologies and the native functions that different mobile operating systems provide."

Does it mean the heart of code, which runs on device remains same with extension of Worklight server capabilities?

Thanks
amit

Comment: Hi Amit.
Yes, Worklight is build on top of PhoneGap when you develop an application for iPhone/iPad and Android.
I did not understand your question, can you please rephrase it?

Answer (score 2):

IBM Worklight development can be divided into two parts, backend services (Adapters) and applications. For building applications worklight is bundled with worklight client-side API, Apache Cordova and jQuery. You can additionally integrate jQuery-mobile, dojo and sencha for creating rich UI.

http://m.ibm.com/http/www-01.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/library/v50/documentation/

http://m.ibm.com/http/www-01.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/library/

http://www.streebo.com/blog/introduction-to-ibm-worklight-v5-0/#.UBREamFgrKM